# Unable to deploy angular 17 app to tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat

Angular 17.2.0, node 20.11.1

I created a simple Angular app and attempted to deploy to tomcat-10.0.26. I get following errors in console.log and index html is not displayed.

[image]

Here are the steps:

```
ng new my-app
    (Selected SCSS and SSR off)
cd my-app
ng serve
```

Everything works great. Sample page is displayed.
Ran following command to build:

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href=/angular
```

build created following folder under ./dist.

```
dist/my-app/browser
```

browser folder had index.html and other files.

Copied my-app folder to webapps/ folder on tomcat and renamed to 'angular'

when I go to localhost:8080/angular, page not found.
When I go to localhost:8080/angular/browser, i get above errors.

This is how index.html looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/angular">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-5INURTSO.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="polyfills-RT5I6R6G.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-GLCPU4OH.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>
```

I tried to prefix scripts with './', did not work. What am I missing. What do I need to do to get this to work under tomcat.

Comment: There is an issue with your http server config. JS files shouldn't have a `text/html` mime type;

Comment: I don't see text/html. It says type="module". One would think, a simple project such as this, would work out of the box on any vanilla server.

Sorry, i misread your answer. Tomcat web.xml looks like this:

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had incorrect base-href.

Ran the build with the following:

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href=/angular/browser/
```

Which added base-href to index.html that helped resolve js files.

Then rename my-app to angular after copying my-app folder to tomcat/webapps/.

Hope this helps for others.